# NGRX - How to set angular app state and reducers dynamically

Tags: angular, ngrx

So i'm pretty new to the NGRX world, and I need to set it up  for this quiet big app, and I need some help getting the work starting.

The thing is every user will have multiple accounts while logged in, ex:

```
User1 :
    { 
      'account1': { infos: X },
      'account2': { infos: Y }
    }
```

so that when the app will get infos it can differenciate between the accounts.
So I'm pretty confused of how I should set the app state / reducers dynamically. Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Since the state only exist for each instance, you can have a property userAccounts which contains an array of account:

```
// your state    
userAccounts: Array<Account>;

// initial state
userAccounts: [];
```

Account could be an object that contains a name and an info object:

```
class Account {
    name: string;
    info: Info;
}
```